# Email PDF File Created with Jasper Report in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, email, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I'm using Jasper Report to generate reports in pdf format in my apex application. i want to email this generated pdf file.

Imagine there is a button as `Make Report`. when user click this button, pdf file should create and send that created pdf file with email.

I know process to create pdf file using Jasper Report. i can implement that part in my oracle apex application. but how could i email pdf file after generating ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have jasper reports, but if you have made it work already: can you call it and get a report back in say a `BLOB`?

If yes, then using `apex_mail` can help you, since it provides the [ADD_ATTACHMENT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23903_01/doc/doc.41/e21676/apex_mail.htm#CHDHCEGF) procedure, which takes a blob as input.

Comment: isn't there any way to email pdf file directly ?

Comment: I don't know - I'm not a jasper reports wizard. I assume it is somehow possible, attested by a quick google search, to set up some form of mailing from the jasperreport server, though i'm not sure how you'd pass on the mailto-info, or if this is possible without using some scheduler. You'd have to ask jasper experts. Although the send_mail way seems rather nice, i'm also unsure of best-practices in this case.